# set precision when push_back on Vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector, tokenize, atof

I'm reading from a CSV, line by line and tokenizing each comma separated value. each token is a string type. and I'm putting it into a vector of type float. In the example below, if for example if the value in the csv is "0.08" , *beg = "0.08" , but in vector v it is "0.079999998"

Is there someway that I can set the precision in the vector to 3 decimal places or something.

example:

```
string line;
boost::char_separator<char> sep(",");
typedef boost::tokenizer< boost::char_separator<char> > t_tokenizer;
ifstream myfile (fileName);

if(myfile.is_open())
{
    while (myfile.good())
    {
        getline (myfile,line);
        t_tokenizer tok(line, sep);

        for (t_tokenizer::iterator beg = tok.begin(); beg != tok.end(); ++beg)
        {
             string temp = *beg;
             this->v.push_back(::atof(temp.c_str()));
        }
```

Comment: *"but in vector v it is "0.079999998""* -- How can you tell?

Comment: By looking the vector when debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `atof`, which implies you're using `float` to hold the data. Floating point values do not hold base-10 values as accurately as you might expect. So simple numbers like this may not have a good binary representation.

You have a couple options:

1. Deal with imprecision properly. You must always be aware of precision when dealing with floating point, so if you want to display that number to the nearest 2 decimal places, do the proper rounding and it will always work like you want.
2. Use integers only. If you only ever need 2 digits of precision after the decimal point, just store the values as `int` which are multiplied by 100. So `0.08` is stored as `8`. Write your own functions to parse directly into this format.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a problem with the float. You cannot represent 0.8 exactly, but no worries -- simply *output* the values with the desired precision:

```
#include <iomanip>   // for fixed and setprecision
#include <iostream>  // for cout
#include <cstdio>    // for printf

for (auto it = v.cbegin(), end = v.cend(); it != end; ++it)
{
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::printf("%.3f\n", *it)`.

If you truly want to store *exact* values in your data structure, you cannot use normal floats. You can either use some sort of fixed-point interpretation of integers (e.g. measure everything in units of 1/1000), or you can use decimal floats (rare), or you can store *rational* numbers (quotients of integers). If you only do addition and subtraction, fixed-point would be the natural way to go.

Comment: I need to value in the vector to be .08 as I need to manipulate the value as .08 instead of .07998.  for example, I need to minus each value by .001 then multiply by 2.

Comment: @Lexicon: read my last paragraph again. Ordinary floats *cannot* take the value 0.08, just like an ordinary integer cannot take the value 1/3.